# How do I completely remove colorama from this?

Tags: python, colorama

I have this code from a friend, but since he's on linux he has colorama in it and it doesnt work for me making it hard to read and/or copy and paste results when the color codes all right there. What do i need to edit out so colorama isnt in it?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests
import json
import sys
import struct
import socket
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

indent = "  "


def ip2bin(ip):  # Credit to converter
    binary = bin(struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_aton(ip))[0])
    return binary


def arg_length():
    return len(sys.argv)


def print_help():
    print("Commands:")
    print("** ipl -i <ip> - Gets information from an IP address")
    print("** ipl -h - Displays this page.")


def lookup(ip):
    print("Looking up IP address \"" + str(ip) + "\"..")

    re = requests.get("https://ipinfo.io/" + str(ip) + "/json")

    j = json.loads(re.content)

    postal = ''
    loc = ''
    hostname = ''

    print("IP Information:")

    for key, value in j.items():
        maininfo = True
        if str(key) == "error":
            print("Error: Invalid IP address")
            exit(0)
        if str(key) != "readme":
            if key == "postal":
                postal = value
                maininfo = False
            if key == "loc":
                loc = value
                maininfo = False
            if key == 'hostname':
                loc = value
                maininfo = False
            if maininfo:
                print(indent + key, "-", Fore.BLUE + value + Fore.WHITE)

    binary = ip2bin(ip).replace('0b', '')

    ipClass = 'Class '

    if binary.startswith("0"):
        ipClass += 'A'

    elif binary.startswith('10'):
        ipClass += 'B'

    elif binary.startswith('110'):
        ipClass += 'C'

    elif binary.startswith('1110'):
        ipClass += 'D'

    elif binary.startswith('1111'):
        ipClass += 'E'

    print("Additional Information:")
    print(indent + "IP Class: " + Fore.BLUE + ipClass + Fore.WHITE)
    print(indent + "Postal Code: " + Fore.BLUE + postal + Fore.WHITE)
    print(indent + "Long/Lat: " + Fore.BLUE + loc + Fore.WHITE)
    if not hostname == '':
        print("Hostname: " + hostname)


if arg_length() == 1 or arg_length() == 2:
    print_help()
if arg_length() == 3:
    if str(sys.argv[1]) == "-i":
        lookup(str(sys.argv[2]))
    else:
        print_help()
```

Comment: I think you could figure this out yourself if you removed the colorama module (and it's submodules), you will see some lines of error, then you can fix these lines the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all uses of colorama and Fore, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests
import json
import sys
import struct
import socket

indent = "  "


def ip2bin(ip):  # Credit to converter
    binary = bin(struct.unpack('!I', socket.inet_aton(ip))[0])
    return binary


def arg_length():
    return len(sys.argv)


def print_help():
    print("Commands:")
    print("** ipl -i <ip> - Gets information from an IP address")
    print("** ipl -h - Displays this page.")


def lookup(ip):
    print("Looking up IP address \"" + str(ip) + "\"..")

    re = requests.get("https://ipinfo.io/" + str(ip) + "/json")

    j = json.loads(re.content)

    postal = ''
    loc = ''
    hostname = ''

    print("IP Information:")

    for key, value in j.items():
        maininfo = True
        if str(key) == "error":
            print("Error: Invalid IP address")
            exit(0)
        if str(key) != "readme":
            if key == "postal":
                postal = value
                maininfo = False
            if key == "loc":
                loc = value
                maininfo = False
            if key == 'hostname':
                loc = value
                maininfo = False
            if maininfo:
                print(indent + key, "-", value)

    binary = ip2bin(ip).replace('0b', '')

    ipClass = 'Class '

    if binary.startswith("0"):
        ipClass += 'A'

    elif binary.startswith('10'):
        ipClass += 'B'

    elif binary.startswith('110'):
        ipClass += 'C'

    elif binary.startswith('1110'):
        ipClass += 'D'

    elif binary.startswith('1111'):
        ipClass += 'E'

    print("Additional Information:")
    print(indent + "IP Class: " + ipClass)
    print(indent + "Postal Code: " + postal)
    print(indent + "Long/Lat: " + loc)
    if not hostname == '':
        print("Hostname: " + hostname)


if arg_length() == 1 or arg_length() == 2:
    print_help()
if arg_length() == 3:
    if str(sys.argv[1]) == "-i":
        lookup(str(sys.argv[2]))
    else:
        print_help()
```

I think people are voting you down because you have shown lack of effort. However, it took me 20 seconds to fix your problem so I don't mind answering.

It might be best to just use my answer and then delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you call colorama's `init` function after importing colorama, it should [ensure that the output is Windows-compatible](https://github.com/tartley/colorama#initialisation) (assuming you're on Windows).

> On Windows, calling init() will filter ANSI escape sequences out of any text sent to stdout or stderr, and replace them with equivalent Win32 calls.

```
import colormama
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import init

init()

# The rest of the module 
...
```